# Wordpress - "loading.gif" from "jquery.js" breaking ssl security

Tags: jquery, wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have secured my WP site with ssl certificate, however I'm still getting mixed connection warning from browsers. I have found it's due to attempts to receive "loading.gif" by jquery. I have tried to find such a call and replace http with https, through I haven't found any matches at all. Therefore I'm asking for help.

Problem listed in network window: [http requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj9ER.png)

Site url: [neposedim.cz](https://neposedim.cz)

Thank you for any help

Comment: That url is in your `pmc_infinity.js` file.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/infinite-scroll-and-https/ in the thread someone gives the path to replace the image and force https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme you're using is Lavander Lite. It uses a JS package called Infinite Scroll, but the version it uses is old and uses non-https links, causing your error.

You can try overriding this file with a copy of the file with the URLs fixed by using a child theme.

Another option is to directly change the URLs in the theme files itself. This is usually warned against, as themes can be updated and you can lose your changes, but the theme is old and unmaintained - it was last updated at the end of 2017, so it's unlikely to reveice further updates.

So, for a quick fix, open up `/wp-content/themes/lavander-lite/js/pmc_infinity.js` and search for and replace:

`loadingImg:"http://www.infinite-scroll.com/loading.gif`

with:

`loadingImg:"https://infinite-scroll.com/loading.gif`

or better yet, download that gif and place it on your server with a link to it from that file.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a simple explanation and a clear solution.

Comment: No probs - just changed the last line to make it more obvious. This is the better solution, as the file at `https://infinite-scroll.com/loading.gif` might not be there forever.